# React Route to a component from folder based on filename

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Given a folder `foo` below `src`:

```
.src
..App.js
..foo
...ComponentBah.js
...ComponentFoo.js
...ComponentBaz.js
...ComponentBar.js
```

Each of the components Bah, Foo, etc export a component matching their filename e.g. `ComponentBah.js` exports `ComponentBah`. I'd like to write a `Route` in `App.js` that loads an arbitrary component from `/src/foo` **based on its name.** I.e. if a component `ComponentTau` is added to folder `foo`, some url such as `/path/to/route/ComponentTau` will load the component without needing to update `App.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file `index.js` inside `foo` as follows:

```
export default [
    'ComponentBah',
    'ComponentFoo',
    'ComponentBaz',
    'ComponentBar'
]
```

Now you can dynamically add these components as routes in your main router as follows:

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import routes from './path/to/route';
const routeMap = {};

routes.forEach((route) => {
  routeMap[route] = lazy(() => import(`./path/to/route/${route}`));
});

function withSuspense(WrappedComponent) {
  return function(props) {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </Suspense>
    );
  };
}

function Router() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        {routes.map(route => (
          <Route path={`/path/to/route/${route}`} component={routeMap[route]} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

But there are two pitfalls in this approach :

- For every new file, you still need to add an entry in the `index.js`
  file.
- <s>As all files in the folder need to be statically imported, you
  may lose out on code splitting and lazy loading.</s> **Code splitting has be done above.**

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that the filename matches the component name e.g. `ComponentBah.js` exports `ComponentBah`

Comment: Thanks! I am posting an answer with my own solution that doesn't require updating an `index.js` but I'm not ready to say which makes more sense. I think your answer might have more merit anyway

Comment: There is a way to do lazy loading. I'll update that too.

Comment: Have updated the answer. Have used React 16 `lazy` and `Suspense` for code splitting. But the same can be done using any other approaches.

Comment: I really like this updated answer but doesn't it require you to import each component in `App.js`?

Comment: No it doesn't. You just need to add the component name in `index.js`. `App.js` will import all the names and load the files from the dir.